# Reduce single tap delay in Mac OS after enabling tap drag

Tags: macos, mac, touchpad

(OS X Mavericks) If you enable "System Preferences / Accessibility / Mouse & Trackpad / Trackpad Options / Enable dragging", you will be able to "double tap to drag", but there will be an annoying delay before a single tap.

I know the delay is needed for distinguishing single/double tap. However it is too long compared to a Windows machine.

Is there any way to customize the this delay parameter?

BTW: BetterTouchTool has an experimental alternative tap dragging, but it doesn't work perfectly (no edge motion, not working in launchpad, etc)...

Comment: With force touch trackpad, click dragging becomes a good experience. Thus tap dragging is no longer needed.

Answer (score 1):

It's 2020 and there is still no known option to control that delay.
The proposed workaround might be enabing three-finger motions but that's not exactly the same experience.